# identify zero and non-zero scenario - with one value (zero) having special meaning

Tags: ruby

I am comparing values in multiple arrays.
I want to flag values that have 'zero' and 'non-zero' at the same time in the same array. For some reason I am stuck.
Here are test cases / scenarios:

```
 1. zero and zero          => ignore 
 2. non-zero and non-zero  => ignore 
 3. zero and non-zero      => this is what we are after! 
 4. only zero              => ignore 
 5. only non-zero          => ignore
```

Here is my code so far:

```
def unique_with_zero?(*arr)
   arr.uniq!
   arr.sort!

   if arr.size == 1
      print 'ignore: ', arr, "\n"
   end

    if arr.size > 2
      print 'candidate: ', arr, "\n"
    end
end

#test cases
unique_with_zero?(30,20,40)  #false
unique_with_zero?(111,0,500) #true - zero and other non-zero values
unique_with_zero?(1,1,3,1)   #false
unique_with_zero?(0)         #false - we need multiple values
unique_with_zero?(1)         #false   
unique_with_zero?(0,0)       #false
```

Comment: Can the array contain the (non-zero) value 'cat'?, or are all elements `Fixnum`s or `Numeric`?

Answer (score 2):

`array.any?(&:zero?) && array.uniq.length > 1`

Answer (score 1):

```
arr.find { |elem| elem == 0 } && arr.find { |elem| elem != 0 }
```

works faster than array.uniq, a lot

Comment: You could write that `arr.find(&:zero?) && arr.find(&:nonzero?)`.

Answer (score 1):

Gentlemen, start your engines!

```
require 'fruity'

def benchem(arr, msg)
  puts msg
  compare do 
    exupery { arru=arr.uniq; arru.size >= 2 && arru.include?(0) }
    krill   { arr.any?(&:zero?) && arr.uniq.length > 1 }
    wired9  { !!(arr.find { |elem| elem == 0 } && arr.find { |elem| elem != 0 }) }
    cary    { mn, mx = arr.minmax_by(&:abs); mn.zero? && !mx.zero? } 
  end
end
```

I changed `excupery`'s (destructive) `arr.uniq!` to (the non-destructive) `arru = arr.dup`, to make it comparable with the other methods, which are all non-destructive.

```
def bench_for_n(n)
  arr = Array.new(n) { 0 }
  benchem arr, "\n\nn = #{n}, all 0"

  arr[rand n] = 1
  benchem arr, "\nn = #{n}, one 1, rest 0"

  arr[rand n] = 1
  arr[rand n] = 1
  arr[rand n] = 1
  benchem arr, "\nn = #{n}, four 1's, rest 0"

  arr = Array.new(n) { 1 }
  benchem arr "\nn = #{n}, all 1"

  arr[rand n] = 0
  benchem arr "\nn = #{n}, one 0, rest 1"

  arr[rand n] = 0
  arr[rand n] = 0
  arr[rand n] = 0
  benchem arr, "\nn = #{n}, four 0's, rest 1"
end
```

```
bench_for_n(1_000)

n = 1000, all 0
Running each test 128 times. Test will take about 2 seconds.
exupery is similar to krill
krill is faster than wired9 by 4x ± 1.0
wired9 is faster than cary by 2x ± 0.1

n = 1000, one 1, rest 0
Running each test 128 times. Test will take about 1 second.
krill is similar to exupery
exupery is faster than wired9 by 4x ± 1.0
wired9 is faster than cary by 2x ± 0.1

n = 1000, four 1's, rest 0
Running each test 1024 times. Test will take about 5 seconds.
wired9 is faster than krill by 5x ± 1.0
krill is similar to exupery
exupery is faster than cary by 9x ± 1.0

n = 1000, all 1
Running each test 128 times. Test will take about 1 second.
exupery is faster than krill by 3x ± 1.0
krill is faster than wired9 by 2x ± 0.1
wired9 is faster than cary by 2x ± 0.1

n = 1000, one 0, rest 1
Running each test 128 times. Test will take about 1 second.
exupery is faster than krill by 3x ± 1.0
krill is similar to wired9
wired9 is faster than cary by 2x ± 1.0

n = 1000, four 0's, rest 1
Running each test 128 times. Test will take about 1 second.
exupery is faster than krill by 3x ± 0.1
krill is similar to wired9
wired9 is faster than cary by 3x ± 1.0
```

I also ran the benchmark for `n = 10_000` and obtained very similar results.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already removing duplicates all you need to check for is if it contains zero and anything else. So after the `uniq!` call you only need:

`return arr.size >= 2 && arr.include?(0)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all array values are `Numeric`), we can do this with a single pass through the array using [Enumerable#minmax_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-minmax_by):

```
def zero_and_nonzero?(*arr)
  mn, mx = arr.minmax_by(&:abs)
  mn.zero? && !mx.zero?
end

zero_and_nonzero?()          #=> false
zero_and_nonzero?(30,20,40)  #=> false
zero_and_nonzero?(111,0,500) #=> true
zero_and_nonzero?(1,1,3,1)   #=> false
zero_and_nonzero?(0)         #=> false
zero_and_nonzero?(1)         #=> false
zero_and_nonzero?(0,-1)      #=> true
zero_and_nonzero?(0.0,1.1)   #=> true
```